# Use of semantic HTML with Angular Material and Flex Layout

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am learning how to use Angular (with Angular Material and Flex-Layout) and one thing that is not clear to me is how to maintain semantic HTML. In all the examples I see around, there is only mention of specific Material / Flex-Layout tags but not the basic elements such as header, main, etc.

I am trying to build a very simple first page and was thinking about doing the following but I do not know if this is the right approach:

```
<body>
   <header>header with other mat elements...</header>
   <mat-sidenav-container>
      <nav>
         <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
      </nav>
      <main>
         <mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>
      </main>
   </mat-sidenav-container>
   <footer></footer>
</body>
```

So concretely my questions are:
1) are header, nav, main and footer correctly positioned ?
2) are they still required with those material elements ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 tags are classified into [content models](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#kinds-of-content).
The purpose of semantic html5 is to structure the **whole page** in a meaningful way. [See comparison between html4 and html5](https://s3.amazonaws.com/viking_education/web_development/web_app_eng/html5_sectioning_high_level.jpg). Talking about semantic html5 in an Angular Component context makes no sense. In Angular you are able to give that meaning to Components by simply naming them. Also the Angular html files are written with a isolated and reusable component structure in mind.

Now to your questions:

1. You should create components with semantic meaning:

```html
<body>
   <header>header with other mat elements...</header>  <---- this will become header-component
   <mat-sidenav-container> <--- this will become main-component
      <nav>
         <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
      </nav>
      <main>
         <mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>
      </main>
   </mat-sidenav-container>
   <footer></footer> <--- this will become footer-component
</body>
```

so your results would look like this:

**index.html**

```html
<body>
   <header-component></header-component>
   <main-component></main-component>
   <footer-component></footer-component>
</body>
```

**header.component.html**

```html
<div>some header elements...</div>
```

**main.component.html**

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
   <nav>
      <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
   </nav>
   <main>
      <mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>
   </main>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**footer.component.html**

```html
<div>some footer elements...</div>
```

2. As explained above, semantic html5 tags make no sense within angular.